# How to optimize my SharePoint 2013 Development environment?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, optimization

I need your help in optimizing my sharepoint development environment. I recently bought Desktop for SharePoint development purpose. It has 24 GB RAM, 1 TB normal hard disk(not SSD, since it was costly).

I installed **Windows 8** and running a **hyperV** with standalone installation of SharePoint 2013. As I installed the machine response was good. But as I started along working on it, its becoming very slow and I have to wait for minutes to open pages in SharePoint. Please help me how to go about it and optimize this environment to have a good development experience.

HyperV setup includes: **Win Server 2012, SQL 2012, SP 2013**

Answer (score 1):

Could you please tell us, How much Ram you assigned to the VM? What Software Installed on the VM, everything on one or mutliple VMs.

Couple of Common things to optimize the perfromance.

- Stop the unnecessary services /Services Application in farm. I.e Search Services, MMS, performance point etc. Please only configure the services application which you need during your development.
- Stop any unecessary Web Application and related App Pool.
- Visual Studio IntelliTrace, stop it help you in debugging.
- Set SQL maximum server memory to a fixed number otherwise SQL grab all memory
- Set all user databases to SIMPLE recovery mode
- set the memory limit for Distributed Cache Service to 300 MB

Comment: Hi Waqas, Thanks for the reply, I am using standalone machine with Active directory, SharePoint and SQL on the same box. Would it affect the performance. I am planning to using seperate SQL and AD(DC) box. WOuld that help. Current I removed VMs and planning below config. Let me know if that is good for my current system configuration(24 GB Ram, SATA HDD, ASUS MB)       1. Host machine: Windows server 2012 where I will install SharePoint 2013     2. Two VMs one for DC and for SQL2012. I will provide 2GB and 4 GB RAM on VMs respectively.           Let me know if this work well with non-SSD HDDs

Comment: with this configuration i think you will be fine. what about processor i7 or 15?

Comment: Its AMD Fx 8320. Is it good enough?

Comment: i think, you will be fine.

Comment: Thank you, Also I avoided the service application which I am not using right away and move my logs to different location and made changes to 4 days instead of saving it to 14 days by default. Hope this should help me start my development soon :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. Deactiveate the features in CA that you will not need, also truncate the SQL log file, this file can take up space on your e drive which can slow things down.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you did configure you're Dev environment, but the search service is on real big resource eater, so if you don't need it, you should deactivate it. The rest goes out the services you don't use but configured and are activated in your farm.

Another thing is that SharePoint loves to logg everything that's going on in the farm. By default the loggs are saved for 14 days. That can be a lot of data. You should configure it so it can't consume anymore then what you can afford of your disk space instead of the time the loggs are saved. You can change it from **Central Administration -> Monitoring -> Configure Usage and health data collection-> Log Collection Schedule.**

[Configure diagnostic logging in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748656(v=office.15).aspx)

And when creating site collections, make sure that you don't deactivate the  [Minimal Download Strategy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn456544(v=office.15).aspx) as this can make a little difference to loading times.

As it is a dev environment, you might do some debugging or deploying solution files to your farm? Working with solutions, deploying, retracting or updating a solution causes a IIS-reset. Read more about it here:

[SharePoint Solution Deploy, retract, upgrade – What causes your SharePoint farm to go offline IISRESET (web server outage).](http://www.jeremytaylor.net/2011/03/10/sharepoint-solution-deploy-retract-upgrade-what-causes-an-your-sharepoint-farm-to-go-offline-iisreset-web-server-outage/)